# iframe issue: loading the page within iframe where the iframe itself reside

Tags: html, iframe

I want to open the page with the iframe where the iframe is self reside.

suppose,  i have a page a.html that possess an iframe and i give that iframe `src='a.html'`, but it shows blank. Please help.

Comment: What did you expect it to show?  An infinitely nested iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you would be able to do that, you could generate infinite recursion, because each iframe would have itself as child. It would look like your webcam pointing at your screen, or like the Mona Lisa [here](http://www.dominiek.eu/blog/?p=102).